# Emberjs - displaying data

Tags: ember.js

I've already opened a topic and delete it, for not forming the question right. I apologize for any inconvenience.

So, the question is as follows. I have a main page, that should display all of the objects, defined in FIXTURES. Now, as far as I understand emberjs and handlebars, the main page can have an {{outlet}} tag, where the content is displayed, according to the url.

My problem is that I have one screen, where on default, array gets displayed and on click, a detail 'page' is displayed. So, I have to use {{outlet}}, since I have two 'pages' or rather, 'router.maps': main and details (see the code below).

If I display array directly, when I click details, the array is still there. If I use {{outlet}}, I have to on default re-direct user to main page, as I've done:

```
    App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource("main");
        this.resource("details", {path: ':image_id'});
    });

    App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
          redirect: function() {
            return this.transitionTo('main');
          }
        });

    App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(){
            return App.Images.find();
        }
    });
```

What would be the perfect solution in this case?

Furthermore, does DS.Store work like e.g. sessionStorage? If I "persist" data on insert.html and then go to view.html, will that data be shown there, when .js files are loaded anew?

Thanks again for your support.

Comment: am I understanding you right, do you want your images list to stay displayed whilst a detail page is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the perfect solution in this case?

I would recommend setting path to '/' for the main route instead of the redirect.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource("main", {path: '/'});
  this.resource("details", {path: ':image_id'});
});
App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Images.find();
  }
});
```

> Furthermore, does DS.Store work like e.g. sessionStorage? If I "persist" data on insert.html and then go to view.html, will that data be shown there, when .js files are loaded anew?

It does not. Think of DS.Store as an in-memory cache, it will be available as long as your ember application is running but does lot persist when browser is refreshed. Ember Data supports many different adapters, if you want local storage you could try the [localstorage-adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter)